# What is the proper way to handle network connections?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

my app is using network connections as in here:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{ 
    .
    .
    .
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}
```

.

```
-(void) dataFromWeb{
request = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL: url];
theConnection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];

if (theConnection) {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
    NSLog(@"** NSURL request sent !");
} else {

    NSLog(@"Connection failed");
}
```

.

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
{
    .
    .
    .
    [theConnection release];
    [request release];

// Here - using receivedData
[receivedData release];
}
```

.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
      [receivedData setLength:0];
}
```

.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection
  didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    [theConnection release];
    [request release];
    [receivedData release];
}
```

.

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
{
    [receivedData appendData:data];
}
```

. Down the road in the app is this snippet (onButtonPressed):

```
if (theConnection) {
    // Create the NSMutableData to hold the received data.
    // receivedData is an instance variable declared elsewhere.
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    NSLog(@"Connection failed");
}
```

What I want to understand is:

- If I wanted to create another simultaneous URLRequest, would I need to use a different connection so that data arriving from the web won't mix up upon retrieval?
- In this code, what happens is that sometimes the code would crash on the line of the function **didReceiveResponse()** `setLength:0`, when the app crashed I saw `receivedData=nil` should I change the line to

  ```
  if(receivedData!=nil)
     [receivedData setLength:0];
  else
     receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
  ```
- I am not so sure what this line is doing **receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the easiest way to handle 2 connections is duplicating the `NSMutableData`. I use in that way, and it works perfectly for me.

Fist you do this in the point you want the second connection:

```
receivedData2 = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response  
{  
    if (receivedData2) {
        [receivedData2 setLength:0];  
    }
    else 
    {
        [receivedData setLength:0];  
    }
}  

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data  
{  
    if (receivedData2) {
        [receivedData2 appendData:data];  
    }
    else {    
        [receivedData appendData:data]; 
    }
}
```

And then, in the method you ask for receivedData2 or receivedData

And when you use it don´t forget to do:

```
receivedData2=nil;
[receivedData2 setLength:0];
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You would of course need a different `NSURLConnection`.
2. You can do that, but better find out, why it is nil, because it shouldn't.
3. It allocates an empty `NSMutableData` object. But this seems like ugly code for me, because you create an autoreleased object and retain it. Better write `[NSMutableData new]` or `[[NSMutableData alloc] init]`.